# How to fix putty/xming Error: Can't open display error

Tags: ssh, putty, x11-forwarding, xming, xforwarding

I do find many instructions and even questions here which are out of date or the answers not helping me. Therefor

## Setup

1. on ArchLinux box:
   /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
    X11Forwarding yes
    X11UseLocalhost no
```

2. on client putty:

[image: X11 settings]

3. on client xlaunch:

[image]

The first time this starts I allow the Windows Firewall rule to be added.

After connecting to the ArchLinux box and attempting to start xeyes I get:

> Error: Can't open display:

On the Archlinux box:

```
 echo $DISPLAY
```

Gives an empty line.

## Variations tried

In 2) setting localhost:0 or 127.0.0.1:0.0
Setting DISPLAY in the Archlinux Box any of the following

1. export DISPLAY=0.0
2. export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
3. export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0

will just display Can't open the display with respective setting as display: when starting xeyes.

Which step am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

So much time went by since this post and yet, nobody answered it for OP.

The DISPLAY variable is the place you want the display to go.

0.0, localhost, 127.0.0.1 are all going to the machine that X11 is running on and not the TARGET machine you want the display to show up on.  It is that simple.  Honestly.. I don't get what they were attempting with 0.0...

`export DISPLAY=<machine_sshd_in_from>:0.0` will do the trick assuming that there is a running xserver on the box.  First use the IP address to make sure it is working before trying any sort of domain name.